# Duda sobre punteros

Tags: c++, punteros

Hace unos dias estaba haciendo un proyecto en CodeBloocks, referente a clases, funciones miembro y punteros, el cual trata sobre introducir 2 numeros (1 en cada funcion) y luego sumarla en otra funcion distinta; Justo de esta manera.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class retorno
{
public:
    int num1 ()
    {
        cout <<"\nescriba numero 1";
        cin >> a;
    }
    int num2 ()
    {
        cout <<"\nescriba numero 2";
        cin >> b;
    }
    int getnum1(int *ptra)
    {
       *ptra = a;
       return *ptra;
    }
    int getnum2(int *ptrb)
    {
        *ptrb = b;
        return *ptrb;
    }//////////////////////////////////////
     //Aca estaba trantando de hacerlo mediante referencia pero no resulto.
    int getsum1(int *p1)
    {
      *p1=getnum1(&a)+getnum2(&b);
      return *p1;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////
private:
int a,b;
};

int main()
{
  int d,a,s;
  retorno listo1;
  retorno listo2;
  retorno listo3;
  listo1.num1();
  listo2.num2();
  //aca imprimero los numeros introducidos mediante referencia
  cout << "\n" << listo1.getnum1(&a) << "..." << listo2.getnum2(&d);
  //aca es donde quiero que me muestre la suma de ambos numeros
  cout <<"suma"<<listo3.getsum1(&s);
}
```

En `getnum1` establezco un puntero, el cual me sirve como almacenador (eso entendí del concepto), luego establezco los *gets* anteriores y lo devuelvo con el `return`. Al momento de llamar a la funciones con el objeto me debería de sumar pero no resulta.

He intentado igualar las variables en una sola funcion con punteros y devolver la suma en otra funcion pero no resulta tampoco.

Comment: por favor lee [ask], pasa el [tour] y mejora tu pregunta :)

Answer (score 2):

> En `Getnum1` establezco un puntero ...

Ya empezamos mal.

La clase `retorno` almacena dos números, `a` y `b`. Lo que hace `getnum1` es copiar el valor de `a` en el puntero, ni referencias ni nada por el estilo. Coge el valor almacenado en `a`, hace una copia del mismo y la almacena en la dirección de memoria direccionada por el puntero, como se puede ver claramente:

```
int getnum1(int *ptra)
{
   *ptra = a;    // <<--- Copia del valor de a
   return *ptra; // <<--- Copia del valor de *ptr = valor de a
}
```

Tampoco entiendo, en esta función, por qué razón tiene que hacer el `return`, aunque quizás, para entender que no se obtiene una referencia por ningun lado:

```
int getnum1(int *ptra)
{
   *ptra = a;
   return a;
}
```

Ahora bien, puede que tu problema no sea ese y que simplemente estés pensando que tal vez, `listo1`, `listo2` y `listo3` comparten variables... y no es así. De hecho tu programa presenta un resultado muy diferente si se eliminan `listo1` y `listo2`:

```
int main()
{
  int d,a,s;
  retorno listo1;

  listo1.num1();
  listo1.num2();
  cout << "\n" << listo1.getnum1(&a) << "..." << listo1.getnum2(&d);

  //aca es donde quiero que me muestre la suma de ambos numeros
  cout <<"suma"<<listo1.getsum1(&s);
}
```

Y, como te dije anteriormente, no tiene demasiado sentido que las funciones devuelvan un valor que ya están almacenando en el puntero pasado como parámetro ya que el mismo resultado se puede obtener usando las variables `a`, `d`, y `s`:

```
int main()
{
  int d,a,s;
  retorno listo1;

  listo1.num1();
  listo1.num2();

  listo1.getnum1(&a);
  listo1.getnum2(&d);
  listo1.getsum1(&s);

  cout << "\n" << a << "..." << d << '\n';


  cout << "suma" << s;
}
```

Comment: Estaba apunto de responder lo mismo :'V  
Pero bueno, el punto es ese, responder y aclarar la duda XD  
Concuerdo, el problema está en el "main", lista1, lista2 y lista3
no comparten variables.

Comment: @Max Si tienes una perspectiva distinta publica otra respuesta, el sitio se enriquece con cada respuesta buena que se publica

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar. Enrealidad los gets de num1 y num2 no pitan nada como tu dices ni tampoco los returns, de igual forma si se los quito no cambian su resultado; en ese momento simplemente estaba tratando de que se almacenaran los 2 numeros en punteros y mostrarlos en el main con `&` de otra forma, (soy nuevo en esto punteros, funciones y clases para ser sincero). Con respecto al main siempre tuve la idea de que los objetos podian compartir sus variables, en donde yo estaba forzando de que `listo1` y `listo2` se uniaran en el nuevo objeto `lista3` para que dieran la suma pero ya veo